# Conformal map between flat and hyperbolic torus with a boundary

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, moduli-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, conformal-maps

I am confused because I can define two very different complex structures on the torus with a puncture/boundary.

For my first construction, I can imagine removing a disk from a flat torus, inheriting its flat metric and its complex structure. This construction is labeled by the length of the disk I removed and the torus original complex structure. So three real numbers.

I can also consider the pair of pants decomposition of this surface. I have a single pair of hyperbolic pants, and the metric on the torus is now hyperbolic. Again, I have three real parameters as labels: the length of two of the boundaries and the twisting parameter of the gluing procedure.  These are the Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates of the corresponding Teichmuller space.

My question is, since I have two different coordinates in Teichmuller space, what is the relationship between them? These constructions suggest that there is a conformal map between the flat torus with a boundary and its hyperbolic counterpart.

Answer (score 6):

Finding explicit relations between flat and hyperbolic structures is notoriously difficult.  We struggled with this in the case of Dyck's surface in the *Transactions* article http://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-2014-06216-8 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0188

Note that "puncture" and "boundary" are not the same (different Teichmuller spaces).